# How to listen for packets In Node for MCPE?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
var PORT = 19777;
var MULTICAST_GROUP = "224.0.0.251";
var payload = new Buffer('hello')
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
server.on(null, function (msg, rinfo) {
    console.log(msg)
});
server.on("listening", function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("server listening " +address.address + ":" + address.port);
});
server.bind(41234);
```

And I want to Listen To a packet from Minecraft PE But there is nothing,  there's no packets I recieve

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on this line

```
server.on(null, function (msg, rinfo) {
```

you should replace `null` by `'message'`. The event you are listening to is  `'message'`.

Then, you have to make sure, that you are listening on the right port.

```
PORT = 19777;
```

and

```
server.bind(41234);
```

are contradictory.